# VLC not working well --- Black screen (with sound) for videos, while other players work just fine

Tags: vlc-media-player

I use VLC for years in Windows and never had that problem. I also use it since my **fresh** Win10 install last year (by "fresh" I mean it wasn't an update installation but a pure installation after format) so there is less room for problems.

Until yesterday VLC worked fine but since then all videos I ran in **VLC** doesn't contain image --- Only sound. I should note that I didn't anything special I could mention to the system - I didn't update the Win drivers or anything of the sort.

WMP (Windows Media Player) plays videos fine. There are no malfunctions with the PC itself.

**Things I've tried and didn't help:**

1. Reset all VLC prefrences.
2. Updating VLC.
3. Uninstalling and reinstalling VLC (updated version).
4. Unchecking "Accelerated video output (Overlay)" option under Tools->Preferences->Video.

   - I also tried to restart the PC after reinstall - No change.

### Update

The video card was most likely to be Asus GTX 570 OC, at the time.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I can think of two options to try:

1. change the output module to OpenGL, you need to select "all" in options to see the advanced options, and this one is at:
   preferences->video->output module
2. check/uncheck "Overlay video output". This option is located at preferences->video

Comment: I must say that option 1 worked for me by itself, without option 2... Why do you think that is KoKo? And also thanks for you answer !!

Comment: By the way KoKo, please correct me if I'm wrong but there isn't any major difference (or no difference at all) between OpenGL or DirectX (or whatever was the former output module) by means of quality image, right ?

Comment: It seems indeed from several videos that on OpenGL the quality is a bit poorer than on what was before.

Comment: That could be caused by a number of issues, something wrong with your DirectX installation, or something wrong with your GPU driver, or maybe you need to update your C redistributable library, I'm not sure the cause of the issue, you may have to trial and error.

Comment: But generally, should there be a major difference between DirectX and OpenGL by means of quality of image in videos? Or there shouldn't be any difference at all ?

Comment: I haven't experienced or heard any difference in playback quality between DirectX vs OpenGL, though wouldn't surprise me if difference does exist in certain formats such as the newer x265 codec.

Comment: Gave you the bounty - If you have any more data to add about why these experiences might take place with the new codec for those who want to have a first idea about this - Please do. Will appreciate and thanks for all the data so far.

Comment: You also have to Set Hardware-accelerated decoding to "Disable" and click Save.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. Here's my solution:

Whenever I played **any** video file using VLC (ver.2.2.4 Weather Wax) only the sound would start. Video frame would show outside of the application window but be black or blank. If I then stopped the play (by clicking the STOP button) and then re-started it, the video would show normally.

Additionally, Windows would drop down to 'Basic' from 'Aero' display type.

I observed that this happened **only** when I ran VLC. If I played that same video file in any other player like mpc-hc (I **never** use WMP) etc, Windows would continue to remain in Aero scheme and never drop down to Basic.

This indicated to me that VLC was misconfigured somehow - a hunch which proved correct in my case.

After some amount of Internet research, I discovered that if VLC output to Direct X, only then this problem occurred.

But then I noticed that OP had already tried changing VLC's video output module to OpenGL but wasn't happy with that.

So I tried the other Video Output Modules listed in the dropdown menu available in my installation of VLC.

By trial & error, I found that **selecting Windows GDI Video output solved the problem**, atleast for me. Now, my Windows 7 Professional does NOT drop from Aero Glass down to Basic nor does my video play quality suffer!

[image: VLC Video Output Module Windows GDI selected]

Answer (score 1):

(Re-)Install some decent video codecs. I believe KLite codec pack is good and is not spamware.

Comment: Please explain how installing codes will fix videos that played properly before.

Comment: VLC was completely reinstalled.  The other answer below is to reinstall the video drivers.  With the information provided _this_ would be my next move.   These are pretty standard windows support procedures.

Comment: VLC has all the required codecs, the problem is a performance problem, which means KLite codecs are unlikely a real solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I found the solution here:

https://kast.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360031093252-Black-screen-when-streaming-VLC-media-player

In my case changing video to OpenGL this or that, DirectX, and so on resulted only in VLC crashing.

What solved my case was (as in linked post) going to "Input/Codecs" tab, "Codecs" section and changing "Hardware accelerated decoding" entry to "Disable".

Answer (score 0):

1)
-> Go to Tools->Preferences->Video
-> Remove the tick for "Accelerated video output (Overlay)"
-> Try and play the movie again, you should now see output.

2)
Download proprietary drivers for your graphics card - I think theres a thread on the forum dedicated to that.
Example, NVIDIA 8600 using the default 11.4 open source drivers (nouveau?) shows a black screen when VLC uses "Accelerated video output".
However, installing the proprietary NVIDIA drivers, VLC will successfully show the movie using "Accelerated video output".

To clarify the default VLC installation with "Accelerated video output" ticked - works with proprietary NVIDIA drivers - and doesn't without.

Source:
https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/455508-VLC-shows-black-screen-when-playing-movie-files-(solutions)

Comment: Some note, I already tried to uncheck that "AVO (overlay)" option. If by "output" you mean to video, there still wasn't any video then.

Comment: Have you tried to re-download vlc?

Comment: Yes - That's what I mentioned by reinstalling... It didn't help...

Comment: What I meant...